# Identifying a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, audio

I was wondering if anyone could help me identify this capacitor. It doesn't appear to have a capacitance value, unless it's the text at the bottom, which is partially scratched-out and illegible. 6.0 J, 250V DC/160V AC. I just need to find its capacitance in Farads, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Can you provide us a better view of the value at the bottom? Also, can you get access to a capacitance or LCR meter, or even a DMM with a capacitance function?

Comment: A teaser photo. Repost so that **ALL** the text is visible. Just because you think bits half hidden round the corner are unimportant doesn't mean that somebody out here can't make use of them to help you.

Comment: Given the size, 6 uf seems reasonable.  T.I did sell capacitors (as I remember) a looong time ago so it's probably polyester.  Polypropylene was a later material.

Comment: That is a big cap

Answer (score 2):

Looks like 6 uF metallized polyester film capacitor. Dot between digits should tell us that value is in microFarads. J letter should tell us about capacitance tolerance of plus-minus 5 percent.

Answer (score 0):

Find a known capcitor and a voltmeter. Hook up the capacitors in series, and then use the following formula:

$$(\frac{V_{source}}{V_{C_{known}}} - 1)C_{known} = C_{unkown}$$

From the known capacitance and the voltage across the known capacitor, you can find the capacitance of the unknown capacitor.

Comment: ...and then you will see that as soon as the capacitor is touched by the voltmeters terminals \$V_{C_{known}}\$ is not a constant but will decay quickly to 0V; and probably it's so quick that you have no chance to read the initial value.

Comment: Why would the voltmeter allow the capacitor to discharge? So long as you keep the circuit connected to the battery, you should be fine to use a voltmeter to measure it.